# R read in a rds file using httr of Google Drive and authenticating

Tags: r, google-sheets, httr

So I would like to read in a rds file from Google Drive.

I know its possible with the `googledrive` package, however I dont want to download the rds file and import it. I would like to load it directly into the environment.

So with a google sheets this is possible using `rangespread()` form the `googlesheets4` package. The main code which does this is a httr call:

```
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
library(httr)
library(readr)

url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nIi-N7_Past8YlirLdOI9ktV3BBvPraGHZZprElQREc/export?format=csv"

response <- GET(url)
df <- read_csv(content(response, type = "raw"))
```

For the rds file I changed it to:

```
url <- "https://drive.google.com/u/2/uc?id=1ZvCT4Ook2yUkPQj4-w7qAfGr7k4ZWt1p&export=download"

response <- GET(url)
df <- readRDS(content(response, type = "raw"))
```

But get this response:

```
Error in readRDS(content(response)) : bad 'file' argument
```

Any help would be great!

UPDATE

Using a google service account token I still get a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` response which is also smaller than the original file

```
# service account token
drive_auth(path =  "....json")

#google4sheets authentication
gs4_auth(token = drive_token())

token <- gs4_token()
response <- httr::GET(url, config = token)
```

Comment: An RDS file should not have a content type of text/html. Are you sure have the link to the direct download of the file? An RDS file is binary file that has been compressed. You can't read it with `read_html`, you need to use `readRDS`. You can provide a connection to the latter function so you should be able to read from a URL, but it's not clear how you are making the connection. The example code you provided is very incomplete and it's hard to tell exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, I have changed it with working url''s so you can run it too without auth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readRDS` can't read the raw bytes, it needs to read from a connection. And you also have to uncompress the data. This should work

```
response <- httr::GET(url)
cn <- rawConnection(httr::content(response, type = "raw"))
df <- readRDS(gzcon(cn))
close(cn)
```

Comment: Does rawConnection always have to be closed?